# Use relative path in .plist made with Platypus

Tags: macos, perl

I want to adapt an application bundle created with Platypus (MyApp) to use a Perl binary contained in the .app itself.

I can set the Perl interpreter the .app should use modifying the AppSettings.plist (available in Resources of the .app). However, I can only use full paths for now. So, I have the following values:

```
Key: InterpreterPath
Type: String
Value:   /Users/kb/Desktop/MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.1/bin/perl
```

Of course, this will not work anymore if I move MyApp.app or if I use it on another computer. Is it possible to make the path relative to the MyApp.app location?

I tried to change value as follows:

```
Value: ./MyApp.app/Contents/Resources/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.26.1/bin/perl
```

Comment: This is more of a software development question, so voting to migrate to Stack Overflow. But I think it suffers from the [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Perhaps you should also ask on https://github.com/sveinbjornt/Platypus/issues. To me it seems you don't need to supply Perl with your app, seeing that macOS already ships with Perl. And if you do, then Platypus should offer some functionality to use that instead of the system one.

Comment: Thank you. I can not use the system Perl as I need a different version (more recent one).